# Header with position:sticky is flickering in chrome when shrinking

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, sticky

I have a **navigation element**, below some other content, that I should be **`fixed`**, as soon as the scroll height is reached. This is achieved with `position:sticky` and works fine in all browsers. But I also want to **shrink** that element as soon as it is fixed.

https://codepen.io/arichter83/pen/xMLyOJ

If **scrolled slowly** at **Chrome** (71.0.3578.98 64-bit Mac) this header flickers, because if the element is shrinking, the **window.scrollY** of the page is reduced, which makes the element become larger again... back and forth. (use "start" to see the behavior)

Any workaround for this?

- Wrapping in fixed height: this would stop the content below to move upwards, which I want.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a position property to your header.minified ID seems to have stopped the flickering.

```css
#header.minified {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #efc47D;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Indeed it fixes the described problem, but it comes with two others:
1.) the content behind the header is moved upwards, see here: https://codepen.io/arichter83/pen/jdLRxP (could be fixed with a new spacer element)
2.) in my real life example the header div has no 100% width, but is relative dimensioned to the parent element (I could fix that manually)